# Get запрос из АРІ С++

Tags: c++, qt

Мне нужно написать парсер который будет считывать данные из API и выводить на экран. Графический интерфейс можно делать в любом фреймворке, я выбрал QT. Следующей проблемой стало то, как осуществить get запрос. Я пол дня пытался установить библиотеку cURL для Visual Studio 2022 по гайдам из стаковерфлоу и ютюба, но у меня абсолютно ничего не получается. Когда я все распаковал, то при следующем коде :

````
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include "curl/curl.h"
#include "main.h"
using namespace std;
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    test w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
   
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
 
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ссылка");
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);       
    }
} ```

возникают следующие ошибки :

Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ curl_global_init в функции main. 
Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ curl_global_cleanup в функции main.
Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ curl_easy_init в функции main.
Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ curl_easy_setopt в функции main. 
Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ curl_easy_perform в функции main.
Ошибка LNK1120 неразрешенных внешних элементов: 5 

Помогите, пожалуйста , очень нужно решить проблему
````

Comment: *"пол дня пытался установить библиотеку cURL"* - ничего устанавливать не требуется, требуется указать местоположение заголовочных файлов, библиотек, и какие надо линковать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужен вам `cURL`, если вы используете `Qt`. Подключайте модуль `Network` и используйте `QNetworkAccessManager`, у него метод (функция), который так и называется: `get`. Он вернёт `QNetworkReply*`, цепляйтесь за него слотами через `QObject::connect`.

Также непонятно зачем вам `Visual Studio`, если вы, опять же, используете `Qt`. Поставьте `Qt Creator` и жизнь станет проще.

Для `GUI` советую посмотреть в сторону `QML` (в `Qt` для него есть отдельный модуль). Но там нужно знание `JS` на базовом уровне.

Что касается ошибки. Это ошибка линковки. Видимо вы не подключили `cURL` должным образом. Также, если вы скачали билд, то под виндой (за что я её терпеть не могу) возможны проблемы с `ABI`. Они возникают в основном тогда, когда ваше приложение и билд библиотеки скомпилированны разными компиляторами (`Clang`, `MinGW`, `MSVC`).

Comment: Мне просто нужно использовать какой-то именно фреймворк для GUI ,а QT Creator уже скорее как среда идет

Comment: @АлексейМоголивец, Qt и есть фреймворк, а Qt Creator - IDE

Comment: @АлексейМоголивец, если вы не знакомы c `CMake`, то лучше используйте Qt Creator, там будет гораздо проще подключить необходимые модули.

Comment: @АлексейМоголивец, лично для меня Qt Creator - основная IDE, даже если я не использую Qt. Это лучшая бесплатаная IDE для плюсов. Есть ещё `CLion`, но он не стоит тех денег, что за него просят.

Comment: ,спасибо,буду пробовать

Answer (score 1):

вы не подключили библиотеку, на что линковщик и ругается.

Если собираете в CMake, то примерно так:

```
find_library(CURL_LIB curl)
target_link_libraries(untitled "${CURL_LIB}")
```

Если QMake, то так

```
LIBS +=C:/path/to/libcurl.dll
```

PS: А вообще см. ответ выше. Ни к чему тянуть лишние либы если все уже есть в Qt

Comment: Лучше пользоваться всегда `find_package` или `pkg-config`, конечно.